# how to download a file(.bin extention) from given URl(https)?

Tags: android, url

When I copy and paste the below Url in Browser, It downloads .bin file automatically.

https://ual-my.sharepoint.com/personal/u297956_global_ual_com/_layouts/15/guestaccess.aspx?docid=1ae092b7a943741309cad71c57b6f7d03&authkey=AT2ubDrTpyzfPCQmjxLYC9c

However, If I'm trying to download the same file by using Android code, It downloads to .bin file only , but contains html code.I have used below code.
I wanted .bin to be downloaded as is as it is doing manually run in browser.
Please help.

code snippet :

```
public static String downloadFile(String fileURL, String saveDir)
            throws IOException {
        URL url = new URL(fileURL);
        HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        int responseCode = httpConn.getResponseCode();

        if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            String fileName = "";
            String disposition = httpConn.getHeaderField("Content-Disposition");
            String contentType = httpConn.getContentType();
            int contentLength = httpConn.getContentLength();

            if (disposition != null) {
                // extracts file name from header field
                int index = disposition.indexOf("filename=");
                if (index > 0) {
                    fileName = "create.bin";
                }
            } else {
                // extracts file name from URL
                fileName = "create.bin";
            }

            // opens input stream from the HTTP connection
            InputStream inputStream = httpConn.getInputStream();
            String saveFilePath = saveDir + File.separator + fileName;

            // opens an output stream to save into file
            FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(saveFilePath);

            int len1 = 0;
            byte[] chunk = new byte[1024];
            while ( (len1 = inputStream.read(chunk)) > 0 ) {
                Log.e("Test","chunk: "+chunk);
                outputStream.write(chunk,0, len1);
                //mListener.notifyActionProgress(len1);
            }
            outputStream.close();
            inputStream.close();
        } 
        httpConn.disconnect();
    }
```

Comment: If it contains html then it will only contain html. An error page probably. What does it say?

Comment: When i launch above mentioned  url in browser,it downloads bin file When i programatically download in android,it always download in text\html format but i wanted it to be in application/octet-stream. I tried to set it by using API SetRequestType to enforce it but it is not reflected always get text/html format only.But i was successfully able to downlaod bin file with application/octet-stream format by using below url. http://profile.gigaset.net/device/42/merkur242_42.bin

Comment: You have not answered my question.

Comment: There is no error page. The file downloaded from Browser contains binary data where as the file downloaded from my code snippet contain html code.

Comment: You keep it vague intentionally? Please give to the point info. What html do you see? What are the file sizes of original and the two downloaded files?

Comment: There is a Url ( https:xxxxx ) with me and Content-Type of same Url is text/html, Case 1: When copy paste the Url in browser its download a ,bin file. case 2: By using Java code , I have downloaded the same .bin file. However the content of both files are different. In case 1 i got binary data and in case 2 i have received html code as its content

Comment: You are only repeating yourself. You are telling nothing new. Why dont you give the info you were asked for?